# Why does DataFrame.replace() within a function not change the input DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Here's the test code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['U.S.A.']})
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()

def replace1(df, col, mapVals):
    df = df.replace({col: mapVals})

def replace2(df, col, mapVals):
    return df.replace({col: mapVals})

def replace3(df, col, mapVals):
    df.replace({col: mapVals}, inplace=True)

replace1(df1, 'Country', {'U.S.A.':'USA'})
df2 = replace2(df2, 'Country', {'U.S.A.':'USA'})
replace3(df3, 'Country', {'U.S.A.':'USA'})

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

`df1` produces `"U.S.A."` while `df2` and `df3` produce `"USA"`

I don't understand why setting the `DataFrame` within the `replace1()` function doesn't work. Isn't `replace2()` effectively the same as `replace1()`?

I'm new to `DataFrame`. Please point out my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `replace1`, you are setting the output of `df.replace({col: mapVals})` to a new variable with the same name: `df`. That is, you are not altering the values of the original object that you provide as input.

Essentially this is what you are doing:

```
def replace1(df, col, mapVals):
    temp = df.replace({col: mapVals})
    df = temp      # Creating a variable that will overwrite the original input variable
```

So `df` is no longer the same object.

---

This would be another alternative, however:

```
def replace1(df, col, mapVals):
    df.iloc[:, :] = df.replace({col: mapVals})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `replace1`, you must return `df` (similar to `replace2`), since your change is not done inplace (like you did with `replace3`).

```
def replace1(df, col, mapVals):
    df = df.replace({col: mapVals})
    return df
```

And when calling it, you need to capture the returned object (see **Return Values** from [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_functions.php))

```
df1 = replace1(df1, 'Country', {'U.S.A.':'USA'})
```

Also **Isn't replace2() effectively the same as replace1()?**

- No. `replace2` uses a return to return the modified value. While `return 1` simply makes the change (`df.replace`) but it does not return the changed `DataFrame`.